# class type redefinition and base class undefined errors

Tags: c++, redefinition

I have the following code which returns below errors
SFDHelper:'class' type redefinition--File=sfdhelper.h
SFDHelper:base class undefined--sfd_metadatamanager.h

```
SFDHelper.h:
class SFDHelper
{
protected:

private:

public: 
    SFDHelper();
    ~SFDHelper();
    //FileAction(Create/Modify/Delete) methods
    typedef enum FileAction { faNone, faDelete, faCreate, faChange, } EFileAction;
    #define IS_NOTACT_FILE( action ) ( action == faNone   )
    #define IS_CREATE_FILE( action ) ( action == faCreate )
    #define IS_DELETE_FILE( action ) ( action == faDelete )
    #define IS_CHANGE_FILE( action ) ( action == faChange )

    //Converts CString to String
    std::string convertCStringToString(CString csFile);

    //Split functions 
    std::string split(fs::path strToSplit);
    std::string splitFileName(string strToSplit);
    std::string splitFilePath(fs::path strToSplit);
    std::string splitFileNameFromNameAndSize(fs::path strToSplit);
    std::string splitFileType(string strToSplit);

    //Storage functions 
    void storeInMap(string line,std::map<std::string,std::string> &mymap);
    void storeInMMap(string line,std::multimap<std::string,std::string> &mymmap1,std::multimap<std::string,std::string> &mymmap2);

    //Data retreival functions
    string getFilePathFromFileData(fs::path fileDataRecvd);
    std::string getFileNameFromFileData(fs::path fileDataRecvd);
    string getFileSizeFromFileData(fs::path fileDataRecvd);
    string getFileCRC32FromFileData(fs::path fileDataRecvd);
    int GetCrc32(const string& filePath);

    //File read/write functions 
    void writeDataToFile(string fname, string data, bool append=false);
    string readFileDataInStr(string fname);

    time_int GetTimeMs64();
};

SFDMetadamanager.h:

#include "SFDHelper.h"

class SFD_MetadataManager:public SFDHelper
{

private:


public: 
    SFD_MetadataManager();
    ~SFD_MetadataManager();
    bool isOpenDB;
    bool categoryTableExists;
    bool taggedFileTableExists;
    bool recoveryTableExists;
    std::string mediaScanCompleted;
    std::string appCrashedInPreviousSession;
    bool notYetUpdatedRecoveryTable;

    sqlite3 *dbfile;

    //SqLite functions
    bool ConnectDB ();
    void DisonnectDB ();
    void fireSQLQuery(char* query,vector<vector<string>> &results);
    //void createSQLQuery(EFileAction faAction,std::string filePath);

};
```

It is a single inheritance where SFD_Metadatamanager class inherits the SFDHelper class.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please layout your code example properly so we can read it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add include guards to your headers:

```
#ifndef SFDHELPER_H
#define SFDHELPER_H

//contents of SFDHelper.h

#endif
```

and similar for the other header.

Comment: SFD_Metadatamanager inherits the SFDHelper.if I add the advised code,my sfdhelper.h class gets invisible.